# trim( $str, "()" ) not working, anyone knows why?

Tags: php, trim

`trim( $str, "()" )` not working, anyone knows why?

I have also try single quotation marks:

```
$str = "(abcd...";    
$str = trim( $str, "()" );
echo $str;
// outputs (abcd...
```

But it is not removing the parenthesis at the beginning and end of string.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of the string and your exact code? It [should work](https://3v4l.org/2c7aR)

Comment: `var_dump($str);`

Comment: It will remove if braces exactly at the beginning/end: this works $str = '(aa)';
echo trim( $str, "()" );
meanwhile this is NOT: $str = 'a()a';
echo trim( $str, "()" ); for this case you can use echo str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $str);;

Comment: Its working well `()Hello World())`

Comment: You need to assign the result of `trim()` back into a variable. Its not done by reference.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce that output with your code](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4BLpbikSMFWQUkjMSk5RU9PT8laAQhgwiVFmbkaCiCODlCJppKCpjVXanJGPljI@v9/AA).

Answer (score 2):

It will remove if braces if they are exactly at the beginning/end. This works

```
$str = '(aa)';
echo trim( $str, "()" );
```

meanwhile this is NOT:

```
$str = 'a()a';
echo trim( $str, "()" );
```

For the second case you can use

```
echo str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $str);;
```

Comment: str_replace will replace parentheses in the middle of string and I only need to remove the one at the beginning/end

Answer (score 0):

approach this as

```
$hello  = "()Hello World())";
$trimmed = trim($hello, '()');
echo $trimmed;
```

For more details **[trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)**

Comment: It will remove if braces exactly at the beginning/end: this works $str = '(aa)';
echo trim( $str, "()" );
meanwhile this is NOT: $str = 'a()a';
echo trim( $str, "()" ); for this case you can use echo str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $str);;

Comment: Yes this is what for the `trim( )` function is used,

Answer (score 0):

It was not working because it had blank spaces at the beginning/end. so I run `trim($str)` first before `trim($str, '()')` and now it is working like it should be. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't care about losing spaces on the other side of the `()` then just add the space `trim( $str, " ()" )`

Comment: Yes, more elegant solution. You are the best @AbraCadaver! And thank you all!